# How to remove underscores from column names within plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working with data frames that have underscores as spaces in the column names. As I understand it, this is good practice, so I don't want to rename the columns with spaces.

When plotting a correlation of the various columns with each other, the column names are spelled out with the underscore in the plot.  I'd like to be able to have a cleaner reading visual that uses spaces instead.

Is there a way to modify the names that are displayed within plots such that I can replace all underscores with spaces and/or rename the labels displayed in these charts to be something different/more clear than the actual column names? Using both matplotlib and seaborn for my plots at the moment.

**Edit:**
To add some more detail as to the source of why I'm doing this - I am building this data frame from an SQL query.  The SQL database has underscores in the column names, so they get inherited here.  One useful answer below is to rename the resulting data frame to replace the underscores with spaces.  Another I just thought of is to import the columns as more readable names when doing the query. This also allows me to change the columns to be even more legible if I want by adding detail.

`SELECT table.column_name AS [Column Name]`

But this leaves another question I have - why is it important to not have spaces in column names in an SQL database?  In theory I could just make it so the database has the spaces I want built in.

Comment: If a column name follows python's syntax, then they can be used as atributes on the dataframe. `df.my_column` as opposed to `df["my column"]`. But that's about it. I don't see how its "best practice", it just enables this functionality. Its perfectly reasonable to stick with indexing and use a name you want to see on the plot.

Comment: I am also building these data frames by querying an SQL database.  Maybe it was SQL that doesn't like spaces?  Somehow I got it into my head that spaces are bad and underscores are good.  If that's not true, then maybe I can go back to spaces and how I'd even like to view the column names themselves to reduce complexity.

Comment: Okay, on the sql side of things you have to quote strings with spaces `"my column"` or `[my column]` which can be annoying. That could be where the "best practices" come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you are passing the entire data frame to the plotting method

Use pandas [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method together with Python's string `replace` to replace underscores with spaces.

One way is to create an auxiliary data frame with the modified columns names and pass that new data frame to the plotting method, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column_1': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]), 
    'Column_2': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]),
    'Column_3': pd.Series([1, 2, 3]),
})

modified_df = df.rename(columns=lambda name: name.replace('_', ' '))

print(df)
print(modified_df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0         1         1         1
1         2         2         2
2         3         3         3
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0         1         1         1
1         2         2         2
2         3         3         3
```

If you don't care changing the original data frame, you can make this operation `inplace`, without the need of creating the auxiliary data frame:

```py
df.rename(columns=lambda name: name.replace('_', ' '), inplace=True)
```

### If you just need a list with the modified labels

You can generate the new labels using list comprehension:

```py
labels = [col.replace('_', ' ') for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with a data frame that I am building from an SQL database, just modifying the columns (and it turns out index of the correlation matrix also) was the easiest thing.
`modified_df = df.rename(columns=lambda name: name.replace('_',' '), index=lambda name: name.replace('_',' '))`

Answer (score 1):

I find `<your_col_name_here>.replace("_", " ").title()` very helpful for this.

Here are some examples...

**Example 1 - Matplotlib**:

```
def show_iris_histograms():
    cols_to_plot = [
        "sepal_length",
        "sepal_width",
        "petal_length",
        "petal_width",
]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    for i, col_name in enumerate(cols_to_plot):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
        iris[col_name].hist(bins=15, ax=ax)
        col_name_label = col_name.replace("_", " ").title()
        ax.set_title(col_name_label + " Distribution")
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

show_iris_histograms()
```

Output:
[image]

**Example 2 - Seaborn**:

```
def show_iris_pairplots():
    pair_plot = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="class")
    pair_plot.fig.get_children()[-1].set_title("Class")
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            x_label = pair_plot.axes[i][j].get_xlabel()
            y_label = pair_plot.axes[i][j].get_ylabel()
            pair_plot.axes[i][j].set_xlabel(
                x_label.replace("_", " ").title(),
            )
            pair_plot.axes[i][j].set_ylabel(
                y_label.replace("_", " ").title(),
            )
plt.show()

show_iris_pairplots()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  This was helpful in understanding a way to do this within the context of plotting (which was what my original question sounded like).  But it was actually simpler to rename the data frame columns and index at the data frame level.  The problem comes because I'm building a data frame from an SQL query and the SQL tables have underscores.  Another option could be to rename the SQL table columns themselves to have spaces.  I have heard it is bad practice to do this, but I'm not 100% sure why.  There seems to be work arounds for spaces in SQL.